# Is there a homological interpretation for the cokernel of the kernel of a map between complexes induced by tensor product?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Let $A$ be a free abelian group of rank 2, and let $S = \mathbb{Z}[A]\cong\mathbb{Z}[a_1^{\pm1},a_2^{\pm1}]$ the group algebra for $A$.

Let $t : S\times S\rightarrow S$ be the $S$-module map given by $t(s_1,s_2) = s_1(a_1-1) + s_2(a_2-1)$. Then, the image of $t$ is the augmentation ideal of $S$, and the cokernel of $t$ is the augmentation map $\epsilon : S\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$, with $\mathbb{Z}$ given the trivial action by $A\subset S^\times$.

Let $p : S\rightarrow N$ be a surjection of $S$-modules (so $N$ is a cyclic $S$-module). Then, tensoring with $N$ yields $t\otimes_S N : N\times N\rightarrow N$. Since $t$ is the first step of a free resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$, the cokernel of $t\otimes_S N$ has a homological interpretation as $\text{Tor}_0^S(\mathbb{Z},N) = H_0(A,N)$ (the latter being group homology), which is also just $N_A$ (the $A$-coinvariants of $N$).

Does $\text{coker}(\text{ker}(t)\rightarrow\text{ker}(t\otimes N))$ have a homological interpretation?